# Method call chaining with generic types (Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern)

Tags: java, generics

I'm getting a compile error that I don't understand the reason for.

I'm trying to create a builder that extends another builder, all using generic types.

The problem is that the return type of some generic methods is the parent class, not the child, which then prevents me from chaining any of the child methods.

Here is simple example:

```
public class BuilderParent {
    public static class BuilderParentStatic<B extends BuilderParentStatic<B>> {
        public BuilderParentStatic() {}
        public B withParentId(int rank) { return self(); }
        protected B self() { return (B)this; }
    }
}

public class BuilderChild extends BuilderParent {
    public static class BuilderChildStatic<B extends BuilderChildStatic<B>>
            extends BuilderParent.BuilderParentStatic<B> {
        public BuilderChildStatic() {}
        public B withChildStuff(String s) { return (B)this.self(); }
        protected B self() { return (B)this; }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic builder = new BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic();

        // OK (uses child first, then parent):
        builder.withChildStuff("childStuff").withParentId(1);

        // compile error (uses parent first, then child):
        builder.withParentId(1).withChildStuff("childStuff");
    }
}
```

Why do I get the compilation error? How can I make it work as expected ?

---

**EDIT:**

I managed to resolve the issue thanks to the answers below using the following 2 changes

1- I changed the BuilderChildStatic class generic to be a normal bounded generic type without the (Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern) stuff,

so it will be as the following:

```
    public static class BuilderChildStatic<B extends BuilderChildStatic> extends BuilderParent.BuilderParentStatic<BuilderChildStatic<B>> {
```

2- the other change is that I avoided raw types in the declaration in main method since now i can specify the type while declaring

```
        BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic<BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic> builder = new BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic<>();
```

Everything else in the question other than those 2 points remained the same

This way it behaved as I expected.

thanks for the great answers and explanation

Comment: Actually, code doesn't show clearly how it's intended to work -- for example, how `build()` method is going to be implemented for these two Builder types?

Comment: Build will call private construct to generate an object of type BuilderParent or BuilderParent  but that is not important as the issue is in why withparentID return the parent type although through generic use it should return the child one

Comment: Awful formatting.

Comment: @shmosel intentional to make the code look smaller so users wont be scared to read the code :) . , i see someone changed it already

Comment: Bad formatting is much scarier.

Comment: There's no point in overriding `self()` if it's already returning `(B)this`.

Comment: Your code is broken because it uses raw types. I think you mean to do `BuilderChildStatic extends BuilderParent.BuilderParentStatic<BuilderChildStatic>`.

Comment: @shmosel I still need need to make BuilderChildStatic return generic type with the bond that it extends  BuilderChildStatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer applies to the original question, not the updated one without the recurring generic bounds.

Using raw types causes the issue. You can "fix" it by adding a generic wildcard constraint, i.e:

```
 BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic<?> builder = new BuilderChild.BuilderChildStatic();
 builder.withChildStuff("childStuff").withParentId(1); //works since we used child first then parent
 builder.withParentId(1).withChildStuff("childStuff"); //now works
```

That way, your returned values will be of type BuilderChildStatic.

Comment: I had to give you the correct answer. as that exactly what i was looking for the question.. but from where you got the idea is it documented anywhere ?

Comment: Your compiler will warn you not to use raw types.

Answer (score 2):

You use raw types, so in first case `builder.withChildStuff("childStuff")` returns value of `BuilderChildStatic` (from type parameter bounds) and this value has parent' method `withParentId`; in the second case `builder.withParentId(1)` returns value of `BuilderParentStatic` and thus this value doesn't have child method.

Comment: but withParentId return a generic B which in this case must be BuilderChildStatic , but the compiler is returning BuilderParentStatic.. So why the compiler choose to return the parent instead of the child although it is generic  and decided when we created the object to be the child builder

Comment: what you explained is exactly the issue. Why withParentId is returning BuilderParentStatic while in the code of withParentId we should return B which is generic andd B in this case should refer to BuilderChildStatic not BuilderParentStatic

Comment: @Hani, you use raw type thus type parameter converted to its bounds, so `B` become here `BuilderParentStatic` (from type parameter bounds)

Comment: OK now what you say make sense :) . I will up vote but the other answer managed to explain with example more

Answer (score 2):

Philip Voronov's explanation is correct (and I've upvoted it), but since you also asked for an explanation of how to fix it . . . the easiest fix is to split each builder class in two:

- a generic parent, defined exactly like how you've defined `BuilderParentStatic` and `BuilderChildStatic` (but perhaps renamed), to implement the chaining/inheritance/etc.
- a non-generic child class that, by specifying its parent's type argument, ensures that clients don't have to.

For example, if you rename `BuilderParentStatic` and `BuilderChildStatic` to `BuilderParentGeneric` and `BuilderChildGeneric` (respectively), then you can write:

```
public static final class BuilderParentStatic
    extends BuilderParentGeneric<BuilderParentStatic> {
    // empty class definition -- everything we need is in BuilderParentGeneric
}
```

and

```
public static final class BuilderChilderStatic
    extends BuilderChildGeneric<BuilderChilderStatic> {
    // empty class definition -- everything we need is in BuilderChildGeneric
}
```

and then declare and initialize your `builder` exactly like you're doing now.

This way, you avoid raw types (and all the problems they bring), but without needing to specify type arguments everywhere.